# OnErrors in PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

Silly question yes... but is there a way I could use more than 2 onerrors, having a little trouble with displaying images since I wanna use an alternate image and a placeholder if the alternate image wasn't available

```
<script>
function imgError(image) {
image.onerror = '';
image.src = 'product_images/unavail.png';
return true;
}
</script>



<!--<img src="<?php echo $pro_imagelink;?>" width="60" height="60"  
  onError='imgError(this);'/>
    <img src="product_images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" width="60"  
 height="60" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>-->

    <img src="product_images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" width="60"  
   height="60" onerror="this.src='<?php echo $pro_imagelink ?>'"/>
```

was thinking of making an if statement for the un-commented html line but not really sure how I could make it so it could display the placeholder :/

Comment: You don't need 2 onerrors. Just write 1 that does 2 things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second onError to handle the placeholder situation. This is what the "alt" attribute of the `<img>` tag is for:

> **alt**
>
> This attribute defines the alternative text describing the image. Users will see this text displayed if the image URL is wrong, the image is not in one of the supported formats, or if the image is not yet downloaded.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img for more details.

So your first "onError" can simply set suitable "alt" text. Then if "unavail.png" fails to load, the user will see the "alt" text. You should be setting this anyway really, because it's used by things such as screenreaders to improve accessibility for vision-impaired users. So really this should be a standard attribute of the image, and not something that you need to modify when the image fails to display. It should briefly describe what the user would have seen, had the image been available.

However, the docs also say:

> Omitting this attribute altogether indicates that the image is a key part of the content, and no textual equivalent is available.

If your image falls into this category, and an "alt" tag wouldn't be appropriate to describe the original image, then you could use your OnError function to set an alt tag to be used as the placeholder text, in the way you originally described - e.g. "Content not available" or something.

Comment: thanks for the feedback Adyson! My desired output was that I needed to display a placeholder image for my project (being an online shop that consist thousands of items) rather than text, I've figured it out by placing an if != statement but now my new problem is trying to get the block to function inside the echo

Comment: I don't really follow. You've already got a placeholder image in your code - "unavail.png". Why would you need a second one? If the first one fails, chances are the second one will as well, unless you serve it from another domain or something. Using text as a fallback for an unavailable image is much more reliable.